# Enable Over-Amplification

Tags: sound

I have a little web book that doesn't have great speakers. I came from Ubuntu where there was a nice setting to enable over amplification. I've tried Gnome Tweaks, but couldn't find anything. Is there a way to do this on elementary?

Answer (score 0):

Overamplification might not be presented in the Sound Switchboard plugin, but there is an application called PulseAudio Volume Control that will provide you will these options and leveling tools. You can find it in the AppCenter as a non-curated app, or you can install it via CLI using `sudo apt install pavucontrol`.

Answer (score 0):

### Install Elementary OS tweak tools

This is similar to Gnome tweak tools, but for Elementary OS

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks
```

https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks

Open Tweaks and go to Miscellaneous, **select Max volume over 100.**